# Need help with url redirecting to indegogo

Tags: product, url-rewrite, addtocart

We have just installed our magento site however we are getting ready to start an indegogo campaign to start gain funding. What we would like to do is allow someone to click on a link (eg. Add to cart) and have it send them to our indegogo campaign for the time being.

We are fairly new to Magento CE and using 1.9 currently. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different areas you will need to change:

1. In listing page:

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and change this:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

to this

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Text') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.exmaple.com')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Your Text') ?></span></span></button>
```

2. In product view page

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this out first thing in the morning. Thank you for the quick answer. I will post an update as soon as I get in.

Comment: I have changed the list.phtml and there were 2 occurrences of the same code. However, in the addtocart.phtml the only reference I could find for the button was `<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>` Is this what I need to change in here?

Comment: Yes, you can change and see if that helps.

Comment: OK When I click on the product and it takes me to the product page the button works as expected. However on the grid page showing all products, I still have the add to cart.

Comment: What's your url?

Comment: tiesforchange.com

Comment: It looks working for me, if you need to change in home page, you have to find the template that is responsible for that.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will look for the home page code and go from there. Thank you for the assistance. I marked the question as answered. You have been a great help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers.